# How to update list in an adapter with Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I work on an Android app where user has `friendlist` with these structure in Firebase:

```
    { users: {
        user_1: {
          name: John
        },
        user_2: {
          name: Jack
        },
       user_3: { 
          name: Georges
       },
   }, 
   { friendships : {
      user_1 : {
        user_2: true,
        user_3: true,
      user_3: {
        user_1: true,
        user_2: true
        }
    }
```

I would like to display a friend list with Recycler View. I do that and it works.

**In my Fragment :**

```
public void getUsers() {
    userDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    Query usersQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);

    usersQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot friendshipSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final String userKey = friendshipSnapshot.getKey();

                final DatabaseReference userRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(userKey);

                userDataset.add(userRef);
            }

            FriendsAdapter mAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getContext(), userDataset);
            mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "loadFriendship:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

**My adapter :**

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserViewHolder>  {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DatabaseReference> userDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    public FriendsAdapter(Context context, List<DatabaseReference> userDataset) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.userDataset = userDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                             int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(mContext, v);
        return userViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        holder.bindToUser(userDataset.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userDataset.size();
    }

}
```

**My ViewHolder** :

```
public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private Context mContext;

public TextView firstNameView;
public TextView lastNameView;
public CircleImageView userPhotoView;
public TextView userDistanceView;

public UserViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mContext = context;

    firstNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_first_name);
    lastNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_last_name);
    userPhotoView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_photo);
    userDistanceView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_distance);
}

public void bindToUser(DatabaseReference userRef) {

    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            firstNameView.setText(user.firstName);
            lastNameView.setText(user.lastName);

            userDistanceView.setText(user.getDistance(((MainActivity) mContext).currentUserLocation()));

            Picasso.with(mContext).load(user.profilePicture).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_account_circle_40).into(userPhotoView);
        }

        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

}}
```

But now, I would like to sort my users in the list, and I don't know how I can do it because my dataset contains `DatabaseReference` objects an not `User` objects. I suppose the way that I build my dataset is bad. Can you tell me how can I do to sort my users by name for example ?

As you can see first, I fetch the friendships of my user (in the fragment). With this friendships, I create dataset with `DatabaseReference` objects related of each users (friends). Finally, in my `ViewHolder`, I fetch the data of each user and populate the view. So, I never add user information in my dataset but only `DatabaseReference`.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicated. My problem is how to sort User objects when my dataset contains DatabaseReference objects.

Comment: You're never notifying the adapter of new data. Does this currently display anything?

Comment: Yes, the data are displaying.

Comment: Oh, I see. You've reset the adapter everytime Firebase returns data. Inefficient, but it'll work

Comment: I call `getUsers();` in my fragment.

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, you're right, I have to refactor that, it's not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data while retrieving from database like this.

```
  // My top posts by number of stars
  String myUserId = getUid();
  Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
    .orderByChild("starCount");
 myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
// TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
// ...
});
```

Please go throught this link, you can find more information for sorting data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: I can't do that, because I fetch data from friendships that not contain user information, only id.

Comment: You can sort any type of data by querying the database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a DatabaseReference to a User object. What you can do is to convert a DataSnapshot to a User object using [`getValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)).

What you should do is to change how you are storing the data to add redundancy. In a NoSQL database there is no way to store denormalized data like you are trying to do.

Your data may look something like this:

```
users: {
  user_1: {
    name: John,
    friends: {
      user_2: {
        name: Jack
      },
      user_3: {
        name: Georges
      },
    }
  },
  user_2: {
    name: Jack,
    frinds: {...}
  },
  user_3: {
    name: Georges,
    friends: {...}
  },
}
```

Then, you can change your `Query` to get a user friends list.

This is not the only way you can organize your data, it's just an example. It depends on how you wanna query the data.

Comment: Each user has others fields I use and display in realtime, I can't update all users in friends when a field is changing. It's for that, I use this current data structure.

Comment: I can't think of any solution without changing your data structure. Maybe you can change the `friendships` attribute to something like this: `friendships : {
      user_1 : {
        user_2: { name: ... },
        user_3: { name: ... },
      user_3: {
        user_1: { name: ...},
        user_2: { name: ...}
        }
    }`

Comment: The key point here is that you have to get all the data you need to display using just one `Query`.